# scss-mode compile not reading config.rb

Tags: major-mode, config

Just discovered `scss-mode` and it's concomitant compile-on-save (very cool). However, I keep getting errors because `sass` it is not reading `../config.rb`.

I can find no variables in `scss-mode` nor params for `sass` (i.e.: `scss-sass-options`) which would feed in the config path.

How does one convince `sass` to read `config.rb` under compilation?

Comment: FWIW, there's an `scss-mode` in Emacs-25's css-mode.el, but AFAICT you're not referring to this scss-mode but to another one.  So you might want to be more specific to get better answers.

Comment: It's proven to be a bad question. `config.rb` is actually a `compass` feature. You can invoke `compass` as a `sass` script (see: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/sass-based-configuration-options/); but it much easier to simply post a `compass watch`. I have been using the `scss-mode` from ELPA.